# WSO2 ESB Connectors - guaranteed delivery

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on an integration project where we want to use JIRA tickets for business follow up operations. The JIRA (externally hosted) is not always available hence I want to use some Guaranteed delivery patterns. So the question, is it possible WSO2 ESB to use existing connectors (JIRA) in the message processor?

Answer (score 1):

Message processors and connectors are independent. This is what you have to do (you are in right track at the moment too).

1. Put your message to a message store. This can be the in-memory message store (which looses messages upon a server restart) or a persistent message store such as an activemq queue.
2. Then, configure a message processor to consume messages from this store. There are two types of message processors namely forwarding and sampling processors. Here you need a sampling processor.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Message+Processors
3. These consumed messages can be handed over to a sequence where the sequence can use the jira connector to create the jira.

Problem I see with this approach is, sampling processors do not support guaranteed delivery (but the forwarding processor do). But, AFAIK, we cannot use connectors with forwarding processors because we need to provide an endpoint in the forwarding processors configs.

You will understand the difference and the pros and cons of two types when you go through the docs. As a workaround, I can suggest following.

1. Create a proxy service which uses jira connector to create the jira
2. Then use the forwarding processor to send the consumed message to that proxy service.

I think, with above approach, you will be able to achieve guaranteed delivery.

Comment: thank you. I redeveloped the JIRA connector and use only the HTTP end point to invoke JIRA WS. in this way I can take an advantage of the guaranteed delivery.